# How to set SessionDefaultAudience for facebook in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I have searched a lot for past two days and I was not successful. I am following the [Authenticate-Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) link for setting up the Facebook native login. I add the following code to `SplashFragment.java`:

```
authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_logIn_btn);
authButton.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSION);
authButton.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME);
```

But this does not work.

In my app, I want to alert the user to enter the privacy mode(`SessionDefaultAudience.EVERYONE` or `SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME` or `SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS` ) to set their privacy setting for their post through the application.

I also went through [Session.NewPermissionsRequest-Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.NewPermissionsRequest)
but how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the audience and the Permission like that:

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null && !session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
        System.out.println("SEESION Permission");
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(mainFragment, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
        // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
          .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

Just change this line to  the audience you want

```
.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not work for me . where do i call this method ? Currently i called in SplashScreen.java class .